# Data stored in mobile using asyncstorage to be moved to database when internet is on

Tags: database, sqlite, react-native, synchronization, asyncstorage

Data stored in mobile using asyncstorage when user is offline.Same data has to be stored in database when the user is online.

This will check if internet is on or not.If connected it will save to mobile else will store to database.
handleFirstConnectivityChange = isConnected => {
    NetInfo.isConnected.removeEventListener(
      "connectionChange",
      this.handleFirstConnectivityChange
    );

```
if (isConnected === false) {
  Alert.alert("You are offline!");
  this.saveKey(
    this.state.projid,
    this.state.client,
    this.state.contractor,
    this.state.title,
    this.state.location,
    this.state.desc,
    this.state.unit,
    this.state.drill,
    this.state.logger
  );
} else {
  Alert.alert("You are online!");
  this.sync();
}
```

};

this is the function to save the data to mobile

```
saveKey(
    projid,
    client,
    contractor,
    title,
    location,
    desc,
    unit,
    drill,
    logger)
  {

   if((this.state.projid)&&(this.state.client)&&(this.state.contractor)&&(this.state.title)&&(this.state.location)&&(this.state.desc)&&(this.state.unit)&&(this.state.drill)&&(this.state.logger)){
   let storedObject = {};
       storedObject.field1 = projid;
       storedObject.field2 = client;
       storedObject.field3 = contractor;
       storedObject.field4 = title;
       storedObject.field5 = location;
       storedObject.field6 = desc;
       storedObject.field7 = unit;
       storedObject.field8 = drill;
       storedObject.field9 = logger;
       try {
           AsyncStorage.setItem('projectInfo', JSON.stringify(storedObject));
            console.log("text1 in setitem and text2 is" + JSON.stringify(storedObject));
            Alert.alert('Data Saved');
       } catch (error) {
       }
     }
     else {
       Alert.alert('Please fill data');
     }
 }
```

this function will insert the data to database

```
sync() {
    console.log('inside sync function');
    console.log(this.state.location);

    const { projid } = this.state;
     const { client } = this.state;
      const { contractor } = this.state;
       const { title } = this.state;
        const { location } = this.state;
         const { desc } = this.state;
          const { unit } = this.state;
           const { drill } = this.state;
            const { logger } = this.state;

     //alert(user_name, user_contact, user_address);

     if (projid) {
       if (client) {
         if (contractor) {
           if (title) {
             if (location) {
               if (desc) {
                 if (unit) {
                   if (drill) {
                     if (logger) {
           db.transaction(function(tx) {
             tx.executeSql(
               'INSERT INTO projInfo (projectId,client,contractor,title,location,description,unit,drillers,loggers) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
               [projid, client, contractor, title,location,desc,unit,drill,logger],
               (tx, results) => {
                 console.log('Results', results.rowsAffected);
                 if (results.rowsAffected > 0) {
                   Alert.alert(
                     'Success',
                     'Inserted Successfully',
                     [
                       {
                         text: 'Ok'
                       },
                     ],
                     { cancelable: false }
                   );
                 } else {
                   alert('Insert Failed');
                 }
               }
             );
           });
          } else {
             alert('Please fill loggers');
          }
            } else {
             alert('Please fill drillers');
           }
             }else {
              alert('Please fill unit');
            }
              } else {
              alert('Please fill description');
            }
              } else {
              alert('Please fill location');
            }
               } else {
              alert('Please fill title');
            }
               } else {
              alert('Please fill contractor');
            }
                } else {
              alert('Please fill client');
            }
                } else {
               alert('Please fill project ID');
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle this using `react-native-net-info`.
Here's the link to the documentation: `https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-netinfo#addeventlistener`

```
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo";

....
  componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
      if (state.isConnected) {
         //Do whatever you want here.
      }
    });
  }
....
```